# how to find the encoding type of file that is selected

Tags: angular, encoding, find, filereader

In my angular 4 application, we have a case where the user can select a file which then gets read and inserted into DB. I am using Filereader which works fine. Now the scenario is the user should select only Window-1252 OR ANSI encoding type file. I should NOT convert the file into Windows-1252 OR ANSI, but detect the encoding type and display a message. I see readAsText will allow us to change the encoding type, how can we find the file encoding type. Below is my code for reading,

```
readThis(inputValue: any): void {
    const file: File = inputValue.files[0];
   const fileType = file.name.slice(file.name.indexOf('.') + 1, 
    file.name.length) ;
    if (fileType === 'txt') {
       this.myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
         this.fileReaderService.fileString = this.myReader.result;
       };
       this.myReader.readAsText(file);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can use some heuristics, but there is no safe way to determine the encoding of a text file.